# How to pass Array from jQuery Ajax to the MVC 5 Action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to pass my grid Data from jQuery to the MVC Action via Ajax.
I have a button "Save" on my page, and this is jQuery code for click:

```
var result = [];
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
  $('#tblMatters tbody tr.mattersRow').each(function () {
    var item = {};

    if ($(this).find('td.qbmatter > div.dropdown').length > 0) {
      item.QBMatter = $(this).find('td.qbmatter > div.dropdown > a').text();
    } else {
      item.QBMatter = $(this).find('td.qbmatter').text();
    }

    item.Hours  = $(this).find('td.hours').text();
    item.Person = $(this).find('td.person').text();

    if ($(this).find('td.rate > div.dropdown').length > 0) {
      item.Rate = $(this).find('td.rate > div.dropdown > a').text();
    } else {
      item.Rate = $(this).find('td.rate').text();
    }

    item.Amount = $(this).find('td.amount').text();
    result.push(item);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/SaveQBMatter",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'Matters': result },
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) { alert("Success!"); },
    error: function () { alert("An error has occured!!!"); }
  });
});
```

I checked the `result` array and it's correct. It contains every value that should be.
In my HomeController I have the following model for my data:

```
public class QBMatter
{
    public string QBDescription { get; set; }
    public string Person { get; set; }
    public decimal Hours { get; set; }
    public int Rate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And the following Action:

```
public ActionResult SaveQBMatter (QBMatter[] Matters)
{
    DBAccess dba = new DBAccess();
    int QBMatterID = 0;
    foreach (QBMatter qb in Matters)
    {
        dba.InsertQBMatter(qb.QBDescription, qb.Person, qb.Hours, qb.Rate, qb.Amount, ref QBMatterID);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index", "Home");
}
```

But I always getting the `"An error has occured!!!"` result... And I even don't get to the action, so error somewhere on the ajax level...
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: great question, this is EXACTLY what I was trying to do, and had nearly identical code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to stringify the data while sending it.

Try:

```
             $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SaveQBMatter",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'Matters': result }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success!");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error has occured!!!");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly! Will accept as soon as it will be available for accept!

Comment: perfect answer, i had nearly exactly the same setup, and my issue was i didnt have the dataType / contentType set. Big ty.